# How to perform delayed evaluation containing function with Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, sets

I was wondering whether there is a way in Mathematica to evaluate an expression in the most simple form, without **any** simplifying. For example if we define:

```
f[x_]=D[x*x+x^2+x+3x,x]
```

by executing f[x] the answer will be:

```
4x+4
```

but is there any way to achieve

```
1*x+x*1+2x+1+3
```

In the other words, i want a delayed calculation like what := does but applicable to the other functions such as D[]. 
To clarify my question, I suppose that function F is defined as:

```
F[x_]=D[A.B,x]
```

in which A and B are big parametric arrays. Using = will lead to a heavy parametric calculation that finally results in a numeric matrix by replacing parameters, but by preventing further calculation which involves, for example matrix dot product, the calculation could become more cheaper and easier. Or,

```
F[x_]=D[A,x].B+A.D[B,x]
```

This was a simple example and i wanted to do this in an automatic way.

Comment: I do not see, how to do this in the form you are discussing, since Mma simplifies any expression as soon as it is first evaluated. Therefore, right after you press "Ctrl+Shift", the expression `x+2x` becomes `3x` independently of what you do. 

Another story is if you make some precautions before you evaluate, that is, just when you are typing. For example, instead of  typing `x*x + x^2 + x + 3 x` you might type `expr="x*x" + "x^2" + "x" + "3 x"`. Since these are string variables Mma will not simplify it. For example, `expr[[1]] + expr[[2]]` yields `"3 x" + "x"`, (see continuation)

Comment: Continuation: and will not be simplified by MMa, while `(expr[[1]] // ToExpression) + (expr[[2]] // ToExpression)` gives you `4 x` as expected for the usual Mma operation. This is not a unique way to do this, there are a few others. However, frankly speaking, I cannot imagine much use of such a trick.

Comment: Does `D[A[x].B[x], x]` produce the result you are seeking?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes D[A[x].B[x], x] will produce what i need but it will perform lots of unnecessary calculations concerning parametric simplification. I suppose still there isn't a direct approach for this purpose.